# Git checkout old commit, and further make new commits

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

FYI: I am using bitbucket to push my git to (I know not very important).

I was working on a project, wherein I made changes, and pushed to origin master, only to realise that master had some major bug, hence I checked out to a specific old commit, in the same master branch by using

`git checkout commit_name`

After that I started working further and kept adding and committing, now I am lost how to keep the following new commits, as well as not lose earlier (buggy) master. Basically how to get back on track.

P.S. I tried using `git push -u origin master` , but it returns `Everything up-to-date`, and nothing gets pushed to bitbucket.

Comment: How about `force push` ? `git push -force -u origin master` ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri I assume this will not overwrite any commits, right?

Comment: @VinayVeluri still does not work, I tried `git push --force -u origin master`, gives same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are on `detached head`. When you did `git checkout commit_name`, you updated your local repository to checkout the code of `commit_name` but you are not on any branch. You are in freestyle way and can only do limited action. You need to go back on your `master` branch.

1. `git checkout -b branch_tmp` to move to the new created branch `branch_tmp`
2. `git rebase master` to apply your last commits on top of master
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git merge branch_tmp` to update your `master` branch with commits done previously and present on `branch_tmp`
5. `git push origin master`
6. `git branch -d branch_tmp` to clean your repository

In any step, I advice you to have a look to log history to understand different action performed.

You could find more information about detached head [there](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit)